# Angular - two the same ng-template with component in one HTML file (How to make reference, not copy)

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

I have the following problem: I create a web application using Angular. I am making a search form that has several fields. I have it ready as a component. Code below:

```
<ng-template #filter>
  <app-articles-filter #articlesFilterDesktop
                       (onFilterFormSubmit)="submitFilterForm()"
                       [categories]="categories"></app-articles-filter>
</ng-template>
```

To put this code on the page, I'm using `ng-container`: `<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet = "filter"> </ng-container>`. By default, the search form is at the top of the page. I also wanted to do so that when the user resize the window (mobile devices), a button will appear in the place of the search form. After clicking on this button a modal window with this search form would appear. Modal window code (I'm using Bootstrap):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="filterArticlesModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="filterArticlesModalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="filter"></ng-container>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Having the same component twice with ng-template in one HTML file, I get a warning in the console:
"Found 2 elements with non-unique id [duplicated id here]: [html from search form here]".

The fields completed in the search form are not automatically completed in the modal view. (When I complete the form on the page, narrow the browser window and open the modal window.. there are empty fields in the modal window and vice versa). As I understand it, Angular just pastes the code and that's it. Is it possible to somehow treat this code fragment (my search form component) as one reference and not a copy?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

I'm not sure about the duplicate ID fiasco. You could remove id's and just go off of classes, or maybe have some property from the component added in to the ID that you can control: id="searchBar{{foo}}"?

Solving the data consistency when you switch between searches can definitely be done.
If you want to have the search value act as a singleton I recommend putting that value in a service, and referencing it from the components. This can be done a few different ways, and there is one thing to consider:

Do you want the search to persist after the page in navigated to/from? If yes then keep the service that stores the search global, if not define it in the providers: [] property of the component that houses these search components (that way it gets deleted each time the component is destroyed)

Comment: But that's what I just did. The problem is that it just copies the code from ng-template and pastes it into ng-container * ngTemplateOutlet = "filter". So I have warnings about duplicate id used in the filtering form.

Comment: Sorry about that answer, did'nt look hard enough. That's a tricky one, I hope that editted answer helps a bit more